# NullPointerException in TreeSet when removeAll()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

From the docs of [`Collection.removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)):

> **Throws:** `NullPointerException` - if this collection contains one or more 
>   null elements and the specified collection does not support 
>   null elements (optional), or if the specified collection is null.

But the code below does still throw a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html):

```
public class TestSet { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Set set1 = new TreeSet(); 
        set1.add("A"); 
        set1.add("B"); 
        Set set2 = new HashSet(); 
        set2.add(null); 
        set1.removeAll(set2); 
    } 
}
```

Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: No it is not duplicate, You are just pointing to question that gives defination of NPE here i am asking something different

Comment: @domdom--Please remove duplicate tag, and read the question carefully.

Comment: "This collection" refers to the receiver of the `removeAll` call, i.e. `set1`. There are no null elements in that set.

Comment: Andy, true. Sorry then, I'm going to hide under my desk now.

Comment: @AndyTurner---Mods please remove duplicate tag..this 1K + guy marked it duplicate without understanding the question

Comment: @EJP that's a bad duplicate. OP is not asking what a NPE is, (s)he is asking why the NPE described in the Javadoc doesn't occur in this case. It's pretty obvious why it doesn't, but that is in no way covered by that dupe.

Comment: Easy to see why is throwing looking at the source of how removeAll gets implemented. At some point `if (key == null)    throw new NullPointerException();` is executed in the `getEntry` method within the `TreeSet` implementation.

Comment: @EJP please check again.

Comment: Sorry for having wrongly voted for your question as being a duplicate; I indeed misunderstood. Now that I got it, I find this a very good question as you apparently stumbled upon an inaccuracy in the Java docs! Have my upvote. However, I can't set or remove the duplicate mark as I'm lower than 2k rep.

Comment: domdom--Thanks do you know how  to unduplicate it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat- Its not or its AND

Comment: @ScaryWombat-- Seems it's issue with Java Doc8

Comment: "Attempting to add an ineligible element throws an unchecked exception, typically NullPointerException or ClassCastException. Attempting to query the presence of an ineligible element may throw an exception, or it may simply return false; some implementations will exhibit the former behavior and some will exhibit the latter. More generally, attempting an operation on an ineligible element whose completion would not result in the insertion of an ineligible element into the set may throw an exception" From the guide - during removeAll - it would query Set s1 which is having null.

Comment: I checked java-8 docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-

Comment: But it may *not* throw NullPointerException if the *specified* collection contains one or more null elements and *this* collection does not support null elements.

Comment: @ScaryWombat-- Thanks ... :) could you please help me understand this i am looking into JDK code to decipher this

Comment: You asked this last month...

Comment: and had a great answer from @Eran - what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that Javadoc's conditions for when `NullPointerException` may be thrown by `removeAll` are inaccurate.

`TreeSet`'s `removeAll` relies on `AbstractSet`'s implementation. That implementation iterates over all the elements of the smaller of the two sets.

In your snippet, that's the `HashSet`, which contains the `null` element. So `removeAll` iterates over the `HashSet` and attempts to remove each element it finds from the `TreeSet`.

However, `remove` of `TreeSet` throws a `NullPointerException` when trying to remove a `null` element from as set that `uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null elements`.

To summarize, the `NullPointerException` is caused by `TreeSet`'s `remove()`, which is explained in the Javadoc of `remove()`:

> **Throws:**
>
> ClassCastException - if the specified object cannot be compared with the elements currently in this set
>
> NullPointerException - **if the specified element is null and this set uses natural ordering**, or its comparator does not permit null elements

It's interesting to note that adding one more element to the `HashSet` would eliminate the `NullPointerException`, since in this case both `Set`s would have the same size, and the implementation of `removeAll()` would iterate over the elements of the `TreeSet`.

Comment: According to the stack trace, the NPE originates from `getEntry()`, no? But that's nitpicking I guess.

Comment: @domdom I could have pointed out the exact source of the NPE, but since `TreeSet`'s `remove()` already states in the Javadoc that it would throw a NPE when trying to remove a `null` element, it didn't seem necessary.

Comment: Now, who's gonna report that to Oracle (and how)? :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the `Nullpointerexception` thrown from remove method of TreeSet. Below is the source code of Treeset's `removeAll()` method

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
167        boolean modified = false;
168
169        if (size() > c.size()) {
170            for (Iterator<?> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
171                modified |= remove(i.next());
172        }
```

The `removeAll()` method internally calling `remove()` .Since you are performing with some `null` values , [TreeSet's remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) method can't process it and hence the exception.

> NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this set uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null elements

Comment: *and the specified collection does not permit null elements* which is the specified collection? The one being removed from or the paramater?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The one on which you called the removedAll().

Comment: @ScaryWombat: "The specified collection" is the argument (whereas "this collection" is the object whose method is being invoked).